# Plotting a differential equation and a specific solution and getting different results

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked the following question:

[image]

In item b, what I did was instead of plotting (using Geogebra) the function given at the beginning of the exercise, the actual differential equation. That did not match plotting the aforementioned function. Why is that? Shouldn't it give me the same result? The animation below shows a variation of the parameter $y'$ for the differential equation (none of which matches one of the solutions given in blue).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you made an animation which is depending on the value $y'$ (you made a slider for values of $y'$). But a solution to a differential equation is not depending on the value for $y'$, it actually depends on the starting point (as you also see in question c and d).

The solution is a function $y(x)$ (thus depending on input $x$) such that its first derivative $y'(x)$ satisfies $x^2y'(x)+x\cdot y(x)=1$ and it turns out that such a function is unique up to a given starting point.

The $C$ you see in their family of solutions can be found using a method called integrating factor. Take
$$x^2y'+xy=1$$
divide both sides by $x^2$ and you get
$$y'+\frac{1}{x}y=\frac{1}{x^2}.$$
The integrating factor is then
$$I(x)=e^{\int\frac{1}{x}dx}=e^{\ln(x)}=x.$$
Multiply the equation above by the integrating factor and you get
$$xy'+y=\frac{1}{x}.$$
Notice that the left hand side is actually a product rule, namely
$$(xy)'=xy'+y.$$
Thus using above gives
$$(xy)'=\frac{1}{x}.$$
Now integrate both sides and you get
$$xy=\ln(x)+C$$
or equivalently
$$y=\frac{\ln(x)+C}{x}.$$
And now you can just say for example I want my solution to go through $(4,5)$ and then you have to solve
$$5=\frac{\ln(4)+C}{4}$$
and then you get your specific value for $C$.

Note that I ignored some absolute values in the integration, which can be done since they do get compensated by the parameter $C$.

Here is a link: https://www.geogebra.org/m/W7dAdgqc to a Geogebra program in which you can insert your differential equation and will give you a slope field and a specifc solution through a given point.

Comment: Thanks René and wow what a great resource as well!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that i could help you!